# Illegal character error when define Seq

Tags: scala, playframework

I've created new Play-Scala project and added my first model class (case class).
I have a mock repository for my model class and when I try to add Seq variable in the repository class, project's compilation fails.
If I create companion object for my model class and add Seq variable inside this object, compilation is succeed. Without any Seq definition compilation is fine too.

Error text is very strange for me: Error:(7, 25) illegal character '\u2028'
I use IntelliJ Idea and file encoding is UTF-8.

My classes code:

```
case class Teacher(id: Long, name: String) extends BaseItem

object Teacher {
  val list = Seq(1, 2, 3) //this compiles
}

class TeacherRepository extends BaseRepository[Teacher] with BaseTeacherRepository {
  val int = List(1, 2, 3          ) //this one fails
  override def list: Seq[Teacher] = ???

  override def getById(id: Long): Option[Teacher] = ???

  override def getByLanguage(language: String): Seq[Teacher] = ???
}
```

**Edited:** It seems like IDE does not show line separators before closing bracket in the second case.
Valid code should be

```
val int = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: You have 2 `\u2028` (line separator) characters between the `3` and the `)`. Simply remove them (or just delete all the whitespace after the `3`) and it'll work.

Comment: @Marth Thank you! It works. I believe in IDE too much :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just format your code correctly?

```
class TeacherRepository extends BaseRepository[Teacher] with BaseTeacherRepository {
  val int = List(1, 2, 3)
...
}
```

Comment: There were not any whitespaces in IDE. Thank you anyway.